# Too many iterations for second if statement which lists extra blank bullet

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

```
$sqlAandM = "SELECT * FROM #_directoryBase_categories WHERE parent_id='1' LIMIT 6";
    $getAandM =  $wpdb->get_results($sqlAandM, ARRAY_A);
    $listAandMMain = "";
        foreach ($getAandM as $getAandMExtend){

                    if($getAandMExtend[is_parent] = "yes") {
                        $listAandMMain .= "$getAandMExtend[dir_categories]";
                        //echo $listAandMMain;
                    }
                    elseif($getAandMExtend[is_parent] = "no") {
                        $listAandMSub .= "<li>$getAandMExtend[dir_sub_categories]</li>";                        
                    }

        }
```

MYSQL TABLE Structure:

[image]

This is currently outputting

Visual of what is being outputted:

[image]

Notice that for some reason the a blank list item has been added to the out put for the sub categories. I'm limiting to only 6 as I'll style them below the "Advertisign and Media" main category item.

Is there something that can be done to skip that extra iteration without directly targeting it through mysql with separate queries?

I don't have enough rep to post images within the body, but they add a ton of clarity of what exactly is happening.

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is (fairly) meaningless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure:

```
               if($getAandMExtend[is_parent] = "yes") {
                    $listAandMMain .= "$getAandMExtend[dir_categories]";
                    //echo $listAandMMain;
                }
                elseif($getAandMExtend[is_parent] = "no") {
                    $listAandMSub .= "<li>$getAandMExtend[dir_sub_categories]</li>";                        
                }
```

should be

```
               if($getAandMExtend[is_parent] == "yes") {
                    $listAandMMain .= "$getAandMExtend[dir_categories]";
                    //echo $listAandMMain;
                }
                elseif($getAandMExtend[is_parent] == "no") {
                    $listAandMSub .= "<li>$getAandMExtend[dir_sub_categories]</li>";                        
                }
```

Because two equals (`==`) is asking if x is equals to y.
One equals (`=`) is x is equals to the contents of y and therefore won't compare the two.

So from the above you want `==` as you are comparing not values not assigning them.

Comment: I think that was the issue @Howli . I understand what you mean. 1 "=" is for assigning while 2 "==" is for comparing. I appreciate it. It looks like that resolved the issue of the blank initial output.